# Separate the response of a Jquery Post

Tags: jquery, typo3

I am trying to send a post-request and differ within the response of the callback.

```
function get_response() 
{
    var data = 
    {
        value1: "value1",
        value2: "value2"
    };          
    $.post("/index.php?id=1",data,function(text) 
        {
            $("#container1").empty();
            $("#container1").append(text);
            $("#container2").empty();
            $("#container2").append(text);
        });
        return;
}
```

I am sending two values to the page I am currently on.
Each value gets passed on to a different function and I receive one result by each function.

```
if (isset($_POST['value1']))
{
    echo $this->function_1();
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['value2']))
{
    echo $this->function_2();
    exit;
}
```

I already tried alot and googled even more... But I can't find anything fitting my situation.
I basicly I want to paste the return-value of function_1 into #container1 and the return-value of function_2 into #container2.

I suppose my brain is more messed up than the structure of my question atm... But I hope it still is somewhat understandable (:

I currently run 2 different post-functions, but as both are set to an interval it's annoying me to have more than one post sent at the same time, it's inefficient in my opinion (the interval is short, thus it could stack up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you concatenate the responses and then split them?

```
$response="";
if (isset($_POST['value1']))
{
    $response.=$this->function_1();
}

if (isset($_POST['value2']))
{
    $response.='|'.$this->function_2();
}
echo $response;
```

And in Jquery:

```
function get_response() 
{
    var data = 
    {
        value1: "value1",
        value2: "value2"
    };          
    $.post("/index.php?id=1",data,function(text) 
        {
            var response=text.split("|");
            if (response.length==2){
            $("#container1").empty();
            $("#container1").append(response[0]);
            $("#container2").empty();
            $("#container2").append(response[1]);
        }
        });
        data = null;
        text = null;
        return;
}
```

Option 2 would be JSON as @subirkumarsao says:

```
$response=Array();
if (isset($_POST['value1']))
{
    $response['value1']=$this->function_1();
}

if (isset($_POST['value2']))
{
    $response['value2']=$this->function_2();
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

and JQuery:

```
function get_response() 
{
    var data = 
    {
        value1: "value1",
        value2: "value2"
    };          
    $.post("/index.php?id=1",data,function(text) 
        {
            var response=jQuery.parseJSON(text);
            if (response.length==2){
            $("#container1").empty();
            $("#container1").append(response.value1);
            $("#container2").empty();
            $("#container2").append(response.value2);
        }
        });
        data = null;
        text = null;
        return;
}
```

You should always try as few posts as possible because it's performance expensive.

Comment: Yepp, worked... can be sooo easy sometimes -.-' I tried the same in a different manner, though I overdid it with variables in the main function of Typo3 (not talking about that, it was just dirty code..) --- And yeah, I wanted to reduce my script from 2 posts to one in order to be more efficient in terms of performance (:

Answer (score 0):

Creating a JSON response.
Something like

```
{
 "func1":"output of func1",
 "func2":"output of func2"
}
```

In ajax response you can do.

`text.func1`  // set this to container1

`text.func2`  // set this to container2